# setTimeout runs twice after the first iteration

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
    for (var i=0; i<sequence.length; i++) {
        allowclick=false;

        function playTimeout(n) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                _bubis[n].clicked();

            }, i*1000+750);
        }

        setTimeout(function(){allowclick=true},sequence.length*1000+750);

        playTimeout(sequence[i]);

        console.log(sequence);

    }
```

problem: I'm doing a Simon's game, and when the computer shows the sequence, it does the animation twice (_bubies.clicked()). It only happens when sequence.length is at least 2, and animtes twice regardless how long the sequence is.

Comment: What is `_bubis[n]`? You should put all of your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hez7c64q/1/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pwter/nvkjxftt/

Comment: working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nvkjxftt/1/ - now what is the problem/how to recreate the issue

Comment: Thanks Arun! When the sequence is longer than 2 the animation plays twice every time.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nvkjxftt/2/ - there are 3 items in the sequence still the animation is played only once

Comment: on the first run its okey, but when it adds another to the sequence, after that it plays twice.

Comment: found the problem, there is a playsequence in the addsequence function too. sorry i was looking for the trouble in all the wrong places and settimeout while it was my bad.
thanks for the help!